# Displaying a default youtube video from database

Tags: php, mysql, html

I have a page on my site where at the top of the page, there is a youtube player and below the player is a bunch of video thumbnails that users can click. Clicking the thumbnail plays the video in the player.

I need a youtube video to display by default in the player box... this needs to be the FIRST result from the database

**THE SPECIFICS**

In `videos.php`, I have my header/footer and some other stuff. For displaying content on the page, I `include displayvideos.php`. The video player is also declared here and grabs the video ID from the address bar:

```
<iframe id="player" width="640" height="385" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/<?php echo $_GET['id'] ?>?autoplay=1" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

In `displayvideos.php`, all of my video thumbnails are displayed from a database. Clicking on the video thumbnail changes the `id` variable in the address bar to change the video being played.

What I need is a default video to be displayed, the first result from the database, when the user first loads into the page. I'm unsure how to do this as well as having the thumbnails below that will also change the video.

**Here is my relevant SQL/PHP that populates the page**

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $tubeID = $row['videoinfo'];
        $title = $row['title'];
            echo
                '<div class="vid"><p id="vidtitle">' . $title .  '</p><a href="videos.php?id=' . $tubeID . '&awayid=' . $awayid . '&homeid=' . $homeid . '&date=' . $date . '&time=' . $time . '&gameid=' . $gameid . '"><img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/' . $tubeID . '/0.jpg" width="225" height="175"/><span class="play"></span> </a></div>';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhere before:

```
<iframe id="player" width="640" height="385" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/<?php echo $_GET['id'] ?>?autoplay=1" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Add this code:

```
<?php
  // There is no id or the id is set to default so play the default video
  if(!isset($_GET['id']) || $_GET['id'] == 'default'){
    // Get the first result in the database
    $defaulttubeID = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT `videoinfo` FROM `DATABASE`.`TABLE` LIMIT 0,1"));
    // Change the $_GET['id'] variable to our new video id
    $_GET['id'] = $defaulttubeID['videoinfo'];
  }
?>
```

If you link your users to either `videos.php` or `videos.php?id=default` it should play the first result from the MySQL database.

Don't forget to change `DATABASE` and `TABLE` to the actual database and table your videos are stored in.

Comment: "*There is no id*" part should be checked with either `!isset($_GET['id'])` or `empty($_GET['id'])` rather than just `!$_GET['id']`, which may result in "*Notice: Undefined index: id*"

Comment: @binaryLV Thanks. Don't know how I missed that.